# How to showSeconds dynamically jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the Jquery UI datetimepicker (http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ )

I need to show the seconds slider on the date time picker, dynamically based on the value of a flag.

what is the best way to enable/disable or show/hide the second's slider?

What I am looking for is a way to set "showSecond" option dynamically.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? The example already tells you how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it with a little digging, I was able to do it as below.

1. Add beforeShow method while initiliazing the datetimepicker.
2. update the showSecond flag inside the beforeShow method.

   $('#datepicker')
       .datetimepicker({beforeShow: beforeShowFn});

   function beforeShowFn(input, dp_inst) {
       dp_inst.settings.showSecond = false
   }

Not sure if there is a better way.